# How to determine the performance threshold in a visual experiment?

Tags: matlab

For a visual experiment, I need to determine the minimum threshold of performance for people when they are presented with stimuli with different contrasts. The matlab guide gave a very useful and ready to use script for data-fitting the acquired data using the following code:

```
xdata = ...
[0.8 1.27 2.19 3.39 5.03 7.75 12.02 19.27 29.83];
ydata = ...
[52.78 50 66.67 75 69.44 86.11 80.56 75 86.11];
fun = @(x)x(1)*exp(x(2)*xdata)-ydata;
x0 = [100,-1];
options = optimoptions(@lsqnonlin,'Algorithm','trust-region-reflective');
x = lsqnonlin(fun,x0,[],[],options)
plot(xdata,ydata,'ko')
hold on
tlist = linspace(xdata(1),xdata(end));
plot(tlist,x(1)*exp(x(2)*tlist),'b-')
xlabel PercentContrast
ylabel PercentCorrect
title('Exponential Fit to Data')
legend('Data','Exponential Fit')
hold off
```

This will result in the following picture:
[Data-fitting example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGWJz.jpg)

Now I would like to determine the threshold at a 75% level. Ideally, I would create a line at 75 on the y-axis, and then determine where the plotted data-curve intersects with this line. Unfortunately, when I try to create such a line using the linspace command, and try to implement it within the existing code as:

```
hold on
thr = linspace(0,30);
tlist = linspace(xdata(1),xdata(end));
plot(tlist,x(1)*exp(x(2)*tlist),'b-',thr)
xlabel xdata
ylabel ydata
title('Exponential Fit to Data')
legend('Data','Exponential Fit') 
hold off
```

The result is an error, and I can't seem to figure out how or where to implement the line and determine the intersect.
Note: I do not have access to the curve-fitting toolbox of Matlab.

Comment: You already fit the data to the curve and came up with the parameters of an exponential. You have the equation `f(t)=x(1)*exp(x(2)*t)` and you want to find `t` such that `f(t)=75`? Using some algebra `t=log(75/x(1))/x(2)` assuming `x(1)>0` and `x(2)!=0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### "create a line at 75 on the y-axis."

```
ax = axis(); %gets axis bounds xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax
hold on;
plot([ax(1),ax(2)],[75,75]);
```

#### "determine where the plotted data-curve intersects with this line."

There are a few methods of doing this. One method is to use the plot to visually estimate the intersection between the two lines.

The most accurate solution is to notice that you have a closed form function which is invertible.

```
invf = @(t) log(t/x(1))/x(2);
```

Using the `x` from that your code produces, we can find `invf(75)` which turns out to be

```
>> invf(75)
ans = 14.0534
```

Alternatively, you can programatically search the curve defined by `tlist` and `x(1)*exp(x(2)*tlist)` to find the parameter in `tlist` which makes our fitted function closest to 75. i.e. find `t` in `tlist` which minimizes `abs(x(1)*exp(x(2)*t) - 75)`.

```
>> [~,tidx] = min(abs(x(1)*exp(x(2)*tlist) - 75));
>> t = tlist(tidx)
t = 13.9955
```

The last method would work even if the fitted function isn't invertible.

Comment: I don't understand on how you got from the aforementioned function to the inverse function you're describing... The function is described as f(y)=a^(b*xdata)-ydata, which is quite different to your inverse function. Also, the x you refer to are 64.0815 and 0.0112, right? Using these numbers I did not get anywhere near you answer --> log(75/64.0815)/(0.0112)=6.1007 or log(75/0.0112)/(64.0815)=0.059

Comment: `log` in MATLAB is base `e` (approx 2.7183). If you type `log(75/64.0815)/(0.0112)` into matlab you will get 14.0480. It is base `e` because your curve is defined as `a*e^(b*x)` (not `a^(b*x)`) and `y=a*e^(b*x)` implies `x=log(y/a)/b` which can be found using algebra and the identity `log(e^x)=x`.

Comment: The function you call `f(y)` is `a*e^(b*xdata)-ydata` which is the difference between the function `a*e^(b*xdata)` and the actual data `ydata`. When you perform least squares you are finding the values for `a` and `b` which minimize the square of this function. I.e. you are looking for a function `a*e^(b*xdata)` which nearly matches `ydata`. Ideally `a*e^(b*xdata) = ydata` for all `ydata` but this is unlikely to be true.